# error expected primary-expression before ';'token c++

Tags: c++

am new in coding and am using c++ to create a program to find sum median maximum and minimum but i get the error expected primary-expression before ';' token in every place that has cout

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[10],maximum,minimum,sum=0,median;
    cout<<"input ten integers,"<<;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        cin>> array[i];
        sum=sum+array[i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(maximum>array[i])
        {
           maximum=array[i];
        }
        else if( minimum<array[i])
        { 
           maximum= array[i];
        }
    }
    median=(array[4]+array[5])/2;

    cout<<"maximum value is"<<maximum<<;
    cout<<"minimum value is"<<minimum<<;
    cout<<"sum is"<<sum<<;
    cout<<"median is"<median<<;
```

Comment: `cout<<"maximum value is"<<maximum<<;` --> `cout<<"maximum value is"<<maximum;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `<<` before the `;` on every line that has it or replace `<<;` with `<<'\n';` for a new line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[10], maximum = 0, minimum = 0, sum = 0, median = 0;

    cout << "input ten integers: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cin >> array[i];
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (maximum > array[i])
        {
            maximum = array[i];
        }
        else if (minimum < array[i])
        {
            maximum = array[i];
        }
    }
    median = (array[4] + array[5]) / 2;

    cout << "maximum value is " << maximum << '\n';
    cout << "minimum value is " << minimum << '\n';
    cout << "sum is " << sum << '\n';
    cout << "median is " << median << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below dummy code to fix this issue for the new line:

- dummy code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;
 
    std::cout << (a < b) << std::endl;  // 1
    std::cout << (a > b) << std::endl;  // 0

    return 0;
}
```

- output

```
1
0
```